# Change language encoding for file uploading

Tags: language-support, encoding, wordpress

Previously we were running a Wordpress site on a Mac OS Server machine. We had several hundred images with Chinese characters for the image names. Now we're trying to migrate to a Ubuntu system and everything is fine except the images. Every time I try to upload an image with a Chinese name via FTP, I get the following message:  "MyImage contains illegal characters. Please choose an appropriate text encoding"

I have no idea how to solve this issue, do I need to somehow change the system language encoding in Ubuntu to allow for Chinese charactered image uploading?

Thanks

Comment: Crosspost: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81465/ubuntu-change-language-encoding-for-file-uploading

Comment: What FTP client are you using if any?

Answer (score 0):

I have that happen with images, and with music files.  every time I try to upload, or add a music file to convert, I got the same error.

Its nothing wrong with the OS.  Its the file name.  I had to change all the names to English, and that fixed it.

I used  Midnight Commander to rename my files.

To install click [**Midnight Commander** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mc/)

Comment: Yea but the thing is, a lot of our contributors to our site uses Chinese systems and as a result all of their images are saved in Chinese. It would be difficult to force them all to start converting their images to English each time the take some screenshot, which automatically adds Chinese characters to the names. Would you have any other suggestions? Cheers

Comment: What FTP client are you using if any?